# BigCommerce University Unable to GET https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{{store-hash}}/v2/payments/methods

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm currently enrolled in the BigCommerce University course, I've set up postman following the instructions of the course when trying to get [https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/%7B%7Bstore-hash%7D}/v2/payments/methods](https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/%7B%7Bstore-hash%7D%7D/v2/payments/methods) I receive a 403 error:

{
"status": 403,
"title": "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint",
"type": "https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/getting-started/api-status-codes",
"errors": {}
}

I've checked again my presets. I have Accept, Content-Type and X-Auth-Token

Answer (score 0):

This error is referring to the API key you are using does not have proper permissions to view payment methods.

Assuming you are just messing around for learning, go back to your store and create a new API key and select read/write for all the different options.